# What is the physical origin of two Hydrogen atoms repelling at short distance?

Tags: atomic-physics, quantum-spin, coulombs-law, hydrogen, quantum-chemistry

Consider two isolated $\rm H$ atoms. They can be in different spin states, but the different states are degenerate. Now move these $\rm H$ atoms together. Now the singlet state will become energetically more favorable than the triplet state, and lead to the bonding interaction with one up one down electron.

But what happens after?

Suppose we move the $\rm H$ atoms closer and closer together, all molecular electronic states become repulsive. Why is that? In a singlet state, we have paired electrons, so there should be no Pauli repulsion between the two electrons. Then what destabilizes the singlet state at short distances?

Is it the electrostatic repulsion of the cores?

Comment: There is electrostatic repulsion of not just the cores, but also the electrons. And by confining them to smaller and smaller volumes, the kinetic energy of the electrons will rise, leading to the bonding orbital's energy going higher than H atoms being infinitely far apart. Then you will have no actual bonding, and it will be purely repulsive from then onwards.

Comment: So there is no Pauli repulsion right? But Pauli repulsion is dominating when we move to something like an Ar dimer for example?

Comment: Yeah, you have correctly pointed out that in the case of H2 already in singlet spin state, there would no longer be Pauli repulsion. And yes, in the more general case, it tends to be that the repulsion is half Coulomb and half Pauli exclusion repulsion.

Comment: Do you happen to have any reference for that?

Comment: Sorry, sadly, I do not. The calculation of that is quite difficult and so it is often just stated and not substantiated. Definitely do not expect the contributions to be equal in all the cases---you already found a case it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$H_2$ will tend to form He ground state at small distances if the repulsion of the two protons is neglected. The electronic part will favor this singlet state until  the complete overlap of the two 1s states if the effective potential $Z \rightarrow 2$ (He atom). However, the repulsion between protons lead to an effective potential significantly weaker than $Z=2$ so this state is unstable.